# Efficient MySQL search

Tags: mysql, search, innodb

I have use InnoDB tables and I need to make a search inside...

Let say I have row

```
 1. asda
 2. asdda
 3. xyz
```

I want to search for asda...

It would be smth like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE myC LIKE 'asda'`... What I want to do is to show 'asda' and 'asdda' becouse it is almost familiar... Is there any efficient way to do this? MATCH(myC) AGAINST 'asda' is only available in myISAM table type..

Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic version would be to use the [SOUNDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) function in MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE SOUNDEX(myC) = SOUNDEX('asda');
```

or you can look into trying for [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), which would be a bit more foolproof but is computationally much more expensive.

Comment: It works in theory... but I have tried `... (UPPER(CONCAT_WS(' ', a.c1, a.c2, a.c3, c.cx, l.cy )) SOUNDS LIKE '%PODSTAVEK%' ... ` and it returns 0 rows... but when doing: `... (UPPER(CONCAT_WS(' ', a.c1, a.c2, a.c3, c.cx, l.cy )) LIKE '%PODSTAVEK%' ...` it returns 12 rows... What can i do?

Comment: You have to convert both sides of the equation into soundex codes. If you only do one side, it's an apples/oranges situation.

Comment: Found that! Thanks for help :)